# What are the instances in Hindu mythology where Lord Krishna and Lord Shiva are said to have met?

Tags: shiva, krishna

What are the instances in Hindu mythology where Lord Krishna and Lord Shiva are said to have met? I came across these bhajans which mention meetings between Bhole Bhandaari (Lord Shiva) and Braj Ki Naari in Vrindavan:

1. [Gokul Mein Aa Gaye Hain](https://bhajansagar.com/bhajans/ek-din-vo-bhole-bhandari-bankar-ke-brij-nari-gokul-me-a-gaye-hai/)
2. [Ek Din Vo Bhola Bhandari](https://bhajansagar.com/bhajans/ek-din-wo-bhole-bhandari-ban-kr-brij-ki-nari-gokul-me-aa-gye/)

And I was really curious to learn more about the specific events or stories associated with their encounters. The bhajan suggests a conversation between Parvati and Shiva regarding their visit to Braj. Can someone provide insights into these mythological narratives and their significance?

Answer (score 1):

Krishna and Shiva encountered each other several times.

1. Lord Krishna and Lord Shiva fought with each other during the Banasura war -

> “He nullified Brahmastra with a Brahmāstra, Vayavyastra (missile
> creating stormy winds) with Parvatastra (a missile surrounding the
> winds by mountain-like obstacles), the Agnyastra (the fire missile)
> with the rain missile and Rudra’s special Pasupata missile with his
> own Narayanastra.”
>
> "Then Śrī Kṛṣṇa stupefied god Śiva by making him yawn and lethargic
> with Jṛmbhaṇāstra (yawning missile) and in the meanwhile slaughtered
> Bāṇa’s army with his sword, mace and arrows."

Chapter 63, 10th Skandha, Bhagavata Purana.

2. Lord Shiva also tried to stop Lord Krishna from burning Kashi -

> "**That Lord (Kṛṣṇa) who is the immanent soul (of all), knew the
> incident of that sort, and sent his Discus for killing Kāśirāja**.The
> infuriated Discus that was very fierce in appearance, had the
> refulgence of a thousand suns. It knew the power of the mind of Viṣṇu.
> **It cut off the head of Kāśirāja and burned to ash his army as well as
> that city**. On seeing that extremely violent action Paśupati (Śiva)
> became furious. Surrounded by his Gaṇas and seated on his Bull, the
> Pināka-bearing Lord rushed at it. **Then Śaṃbhu looked at the Sudarśana
> Discus at the outset and discharged his Pāśupata missile in front of
> it, like an ominous calamity.** Formerly Śaṃbhu had secured a boon from
> Viṣṇu who had been pleased by his devotion: “On being remembered by
> you I shall invigorate your missile. But if you go against me, it will
> become lustreless (and ineffective).” **When this Pāśupata missile which
> was (usually) terrible, became futile and when Vārāṇasī was burned,
> the Bull-bannered Lord became afraid. Then he eulogized the Primordial
> Puruṣottama, the cause of all the worlds."**

Puruṣottama-kṣetra-māhātmya, Vaishnava Kanda, Skanda Purana.

Answer (score 1):

Māhābhārata Describes Bhagavana Shiva meeting with Sri Krishna after the Latter appeased him with a long Penance after getting Pāsupata Diksa from Rishi Upamanyu.

### Māhābhārata, Anusāsana Parva, Ch 14 (Gitapress)

[image]

The following chapter describes how Sri Krishna was Granted several Boons by Māhādeva and Pārvati including the boons of 10,000 sons and 16,000 wives.

[image]
[image]

> The blessed Krishna said, 'Bowing my head with great joy unto that
> mass of energy and effulgence, I said these words unto the great
> Deity, with a heart filled with gladness,--Firmness in virtue, the
> slaughter of foes in battle, the highest fame, the greatest might,
> devotion to Yoga, thy adjacence, and hundreds upon hundreds of
> children, these are the boons I solicit of thee,--So be it,--said
> Sankara repeating the words I had uttered. After this, the mother of
> the universe, the upholders of all things, who cleanses, all things,
> viz., the spouse of Sarva, that vast receptacle of penances said with
> a restrained soul these words unto me,--'The puissant Mahadeva has
> granted thee, O sinless one, a son who shall be named Samva. Do thou
> take from me also eight boons which thou choosest. I shall certainly
> grant them to thee.--Bowing unto her with a bend of my head, I said
> unto her, O son of Pandu,--I solicit from thee non-anger against the
> Brahmanas, grace of my father, a hundred sons, the highest enjoyments,
> love for my family, the grace of my mother, the attainment of
> tranquillity and peace, and cleverness in every act!'
>
> "Uma said, 'It shall be even so, O thou that art possessed of prowess
> and puissance equal to that of a celestial. I never say what is
> untrue. Thou shalt have sixteen thousand wives. Thy love for them and
> theirs also for thee shall be unlimited. From all thy kinsmen also,
> thou shalt receive the highest affection. Thy body too shall be most
> beautiful. Seven thousand guests will daily feed at thy palace.'

The Above Anecdote is also recorded in several Purānas such as Siva purāna, Linga Purana, Kurma purana, Devi Bhagavata etc with a few variations.

[image]

One can read the english translation of the above anecdote from Kesari mohan Ganguly's translation which is provided below-

https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a014.htm

https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a015.htm

Comment: You should translate those lines into English. Though they are useful, they are only so for people who know to read Devanagari.

Comment: Added links for english translations

Comment: Thanks for doing that. Actually, though, answers are supposed to be self-contained, so you should paste the relevant verses into your post.